# Inner Join with similar IDs

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, aggregate, inner-join

I have two tables, say:

```
Table 1

id, name, place
1, a, b
2, c, d
3, e, f

Table 2

id,text
1, hello
1, bye
1, what
2, tired
```

Desired Output

```
id, name, place, text
1, a, b, hello or bye or what (any one of the three)
2, c, d, tired
```

I have seen a lot of posts but I couldn't find anything similar. I am new to SQL/Postgresql. I am doing it in PostgreSQL.

Comment: So you want an array or what?

Comment: @andronicus I just want any 1 value, since it's a text I couldn't use min() or max()

Comment: This isn't clear. Please clarify via edits, not comments. Use enough words. In code questions please give a [mre]. [ask]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `DISTINCT ON` here and arbitrarily just take the alphabetically lowest text from the second table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (t1.id) t1.id, t1.name, t1.place, t2.text
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
ORDER BY
    t1.id,
    t2.text;
```

[image: screen capture from demo below]

### Demo

Comment: This works perfectly fine, thank you so much. I am also figuring out how to accept the answer, also my reputation isn't high enough to have an effect on the upvotes, sorry.

Comment: @AkifBeig . . . I just want to point out that `DISTINCT ON` is a (very convenient) Postgres extension to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate multiple values in an array and pick a random value (postgres syntax):

```
select t1.id, (array_agg(t2.text))[floor(random() * count(t2.text) + 1)::int]
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
group by t1.id
```

Or a bit faster, but will pick first value only:

```
select t1.id, (array_agg(t2.text))[1]
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
group by t1.id
```

Comment: OP needs in one value from all possible, not all aggregated. Citate: *any one of the three*. Use MAX(), MIN() or similar except STRING_AGG().

Comment: @Akina ok, I didn't understand that, hence the question in the comment. Corrected, thank you.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm creating an array of all values for a given id and pick a random one (or first one in the second snipper)

Comment: Nice one +1 ... wouldn't have thought to do this.

Comment: @Andronicus this was giving me error t1.name must appear in group by clause, t1.place must appear in the group by clause. I copy-pasted the exact solution

Comment: @AkifBeig didn't you type `t1.*` or something like that?

Comment: I tried both t1.* and t1.id, t1.name,t1.place the same error for both @Andronicus

Comment: If you copy-pasted, it would work. All columns other than `t2.text` should be in `group by`

Answer (score -1):

You would write something along the lines of

select t1.id, name, place, text from `table 1` as t1
join `table 2` as t2 on t2.id = t1.id 
group by t1.id